# How to return the last of two values in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I stumbled across this forum while trying to solve an issue with a data set I am trying to convert into a table.
My data includes both numbers and two colors in column A, in descending order. Is there a way I can get column B to reference the last occurrence of the two colors? 
IE:
Something that looks like this :

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: people are happy to help but you should try to ask the question with more clarity. So 1) Provide a sample XL file with the raw data that you have, 2) Provide a clear example of the result that you are looking for. For example you say that your data is in descending order, however it looks like it's in ascending order in the image provided. As an aside have you tried using the formulas in XL. "MAX", "MATCH" and "INDEX"? These usually solve such questions.

Comment: Needs clear "before" and "after" examples.

Comment: column B is the desired result.

Comment: Edit your question to show what you have tried, and what the results were, of your efforts to convert your data set into a table.

Answer (score 0):

This formula seems to do what you say you want:

```
B2: =IF(OR(A2={"RED","GREEN"}),"", INDEX($A:$A, MAX(($A$2:$A2={"RED","GREEN"})*ROW($A$2:$A2))))
```

*In some earlier versions of Excel, you may need to "confirm" this formula by holding down <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> while hitting <kbd>enter</kbd>.  If you do this correctly, Excel will place braces `{...}` around the formula as observed in the formula bar*

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

In `B2`, copied down until blank :

```
=IF((A2="")+ISTEXT(A2),"",LOOKUP("zzz",A$1:A2))
```

[image]